# How to pass additional data to a reactive dynamic form in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I have an array with combination of editable (will be `formControl` object) and read-only data(will be a static text on the HTML). Is there a way to do that in Angular? I can use `FormArrays` and `FormGroups` to add this static text, too but it feels wrong. Let me elaborate on the problem with an example:

Say, I have a JSON object as follows:

```
itemArray = [{
  title: 'fancy item', // not a member of the form (read-only)
  quantity: 0 // member of the form (editable)
},
{
  title: 'weird item', // not a member of the form (read-only)
  quantity: 1 // member of the form (editabe)
}
]
```

I use FormArrays for the `quantity` field of the items.

```
this.formItems = new FormArray([
      new FormGroup(
        {
          quantity: new FormControl(1, Validators.required),
          title: new FormControl('Fancy item') // Readonly text for form group. What's the best way to add a enrichment data for a form group?
        }
      ),
      new FormGroup(
        {
          quantity: new FormControl(1, Validators.required),
          title: new FormControl('Weird item') // Readonly text for form group. What's the best way to add a enrichment data for a form group?
        }
      )
    ]
);
```

However, the title is not an editable item. What's the best way to add additional data to a `FormGroup`?

Otherwise, I have to create another separate array called `items` to manage this additional and non-editable data. So, I can split the fields of item into two separate objects. 1) `staticDataForItems`, 2) `editableDataForItems`.

```
this.staticDataForItems = [{
    title: 'Weird item',
  }
];

this.editableDataForItems = new FormArray([
      new FormGroup(
        {
          quantity: new FormControl(1, Validators.required),
        }
      ),
      new FormGroup(
        {
          quantity: new FormControl(1, Validators.required),
        }
      )
    ]
);
```

This is a solution that I would not prefer. Because, in my use case, I can add items to the array or delete "items" from the array. I don't want to deal with 2 arrays(items and `formArray`) which is not future-proof.

If I have a combination of read-only(read-only HTML element) and editable data(input HTML element) data, how can I combine those two arrays into 1 single array.

I want to both benefit from form validation and I would like to add additional data in a good way.

You can find a working example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gw1c6d?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks.

Comment: so you want the title control to be readonly, but still be part of the value of the form group when you use `formItems[someIndex].value`?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I even don't want to have "title" to be a formControl because it is not a control. It is just a static text which contains descriptive information about item.

Answer (score 0):

I simply pass the static values in the submit function like this:

```
`<form [formGroup]="prodForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddToCart(
    product._id, 
    product.title, 
    product.price, 
    product.sale,
    prodForm.value)">`
```

Then prodForm.value holds the controls for size, color, and qty of the item.